# How to submit a form without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

```
<form name="form3"   action="priority.php? id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" method="post">
  <select name="taskOption2" id="taskOption2" onchange="this.form.submit();" >
<option  selected disabled hidden> <?php echo $row['priority'] ?> </option>
 <option value="High">High</option>
<option value="Normal">Normal</option>
<option value="Low">Low</option>
</select>
<noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit" > </noscript>
</form>
```

How to submit a form without page refresh??Thanks

Comment: There are lots of Ajax tutorials out there. Try those, then repost if you have specific questions or something isn't working. I suggest using jQuery for that.

Comment: You have tagged the question with ajax so you clearly have somewhat of an understanding what you need to do. Show us what you tried so far and then we can help you with a specific issue you run into.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="formid" name="form3"   action="priority.php? id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" method="post">
<select name="taskOption2" id="taskOption2" onchange="this.form.submit();" >
<option  selected disabled hidden> <?php echo $row['priority'] ?> </option>
<option value="High">High</option>
<option value="Normal">Normal</option>
<option value="Low">Low</option>
</select>
<noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit" > </noscript>
</form>


<script>

$("#formid").submit(function(e) {

var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#formid").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
     });

e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
<script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question a ***good answer*** will have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way for the OP and for future visitors to Stack Overflow.

Comment: thank you for help. It is work for me

Comment: @yeunhangyeung if his answer worked for you, you might want to think about accepting it.. ;)